# radical of an ideal in the polynomial ring $k[x,y]$

Tags: commutative-algebra

How can I compute the radical of an ideal? I suppose that there no exist an algorithm for compute it. But in the case of polynomials rings? there exist an algorithm? 
I need to compute the radical of the ideal generated by $ (x^2y , xy^3) $ in the ring of polynomials $ k[x,y]$ where $k$ is any field.

Comment: You should look into [Groebner bases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groebner_Basis). [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95217/methods-to-check-if-an-ideal-of-a-polynomial-ring-is-prime-or-at-least-radical/95525#95525) related question might also prove useful.

Answer (score 2):

There are indeed algorithms for the polynomial rings, based on the notion of Groebner bases —you can learn about this from David Cox *et al.*'s book *Varieties, Ideals and Alrgorithms.*

Those algorithms are actually implemented in several computar algebra systems. I usually use Macaulay2, which google can find for you.

Your ideal $I=(x^2y,xy^3)$ is what's called a *monomial ideal*, because it is generated by monomials; it has the nice property that a polynomial belongs to $I$ if and only if each of its monomials belongs to $I$, and you can probably prove this easily. It is not hard to see that its radical is also generated by monomials, and then you can probably see *which* monomials you need in this specific case. I'll let you try your hand at this before giving you the answer...

Comment: Using that you said, I can try with all the options of monomials of less degree than $ x^2y , xy^3 $ that belongs to the radical, and are not in I . There is only one. And is the monoial xy. So the radical is generated by  $ xy, x^2y , xy^3 $