# Rational quartic curve in $\mathbb P^3$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

By using similar arguments to the ones from [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/227255/121097) to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167321/krull-dimension-of-mathbbcx-1-x-2-x-3-x-4-left-x-1x-3-x-22-x-2-x-4-x), I can prove that the homogeneous coordinate ring of the *rational quartic curve* in $\mathbb P^3$, that is, $$R = K[x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4]/\left< x_1^2x_3-x_2^3,x_1x_3^2-x_2^2x_4,x_2x_4^2-x_3^3,x_1x_4-x_2 x_3\right>,$$ is isomorphic to $K[s^4,s^3t,st^3,t^4]$. (This is also Exercise 18.8 in Eisenbud, *Commutative Algebra with a View Toward Algebraic Geometry*.)

I'm interested in geometric arguments which I expect to be simpler than the algebraic ones. References are also welcome.

**Edit.** There is some connection with [this topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95217/methods-to-check-if-an-ideal-of-a-polynomial-ring-is-prime-or-at-least-radical/95525#95525) where it is proved that $R$ is an integral domain.

Comment: I am afraid there is no simple geometric argument.

Comment: The problem is at some point we have to do direct computations with the algebras. The only thing which is non-trivial is to show $R$ is integral (or enough it is reduced). By localizations or using $Proj(R)$, we can see that the only prime $\mathfrak p$ of $R$ where $R_{\mathfrak p}$ could be non-reduced is the maximal ideal generated by $x_1,\dots, x_4$. This maximal ideal is completely out of control in $Proj(R)$. So I don't have a purely geometric proof.