# Normalization of cone over twisted quartic curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, algebraic-curves, projective-geometry

For smooth projective varieties $Y \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ we know that the coordinate ring $S(Y)$ may or may not be integrally closed. If $S(Y)$ is normal, we say $Y$ is projectievly normal. This notion measures normality of the affine cone $C(Y) \subset \mathbb{A}^{n+1}$ over $Y$.

A standard example of non-projectively normal variety is the twisted quartic in $\mathbb{P}^1 \hookrightarrow \mathbb{P}^3$, given by the embedding
$$ [u:v]\mapsto [u^4:u^3v:uv^3:v^4] $$
This embedding is obtained via projecting the rational normal curve in $\mathbb{P}^1 \hookrightarrow \mathbb{P}^4$ given by
$$ [u:v]\mapsto [u^4:u^3v:u^2v^2:uv^3:v^4] $$
on a suitable hyperplane in $\mathbb{P}^4$.

Call $Y_1$ the twisted quartic in $\mathbb{P}^3$ and $Y_2$ the rational normal curve in $\mathbb{P}^4$. We have that $S(Y_2)$ is the integral closure of $S(Y_1)$. Therefore, $C(Y_2)$ is the normalization of $C(Y_1)$.

**Question**

My question is the following. How do I visualize the map $C(Y_2) \rightarrow C(Y_1)$?

**Edit**

Using the equations in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/283476/rational-quartic-curve-in-mathbb-p3), taking the jacobian matrix and checking for where the rank drops below 2, it looks like the cone $C(Y_1)$ is smooth away from the vertex. Thus, $C(Y_1)$ is already $R_1$. Is then the normalization happening just at level of structure sheaves, to ensure the $S_2$ property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I kind of came up with some way of visualizing the map in a cohomological way instead of a geometric way.

By restricting the sheaf $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}(1)$ to $Y_1$ we get $\mathcal{O}_{Y_1}(1)\cong \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(4)$, however the restricting of global sections $H^0(\mathbb{P}^3,\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}(1))\to H^0(Y_1,\mathcal{O}_{Y_1}(1))$ is not surjective because we miss a section $u^2v^2$ by dimension counting. Now this means that the map
$$
\mathrm{Spec}\bigoplus_{m\geq 0}  H^0(Y_1,\mathcal{O}_{Y_1}(m))\to \mathrm{Spec}\bigoplus_{m\geq 0}  H^0(\mathbb{P}^3,\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}(m))
$$
is not a closed imersion. This map is exactly $C(Y_2)\to C(\mathbb{P}^3)=\mathbb{A}^4$, and the image of this map is $C(Y_1)$.

This is also why I found online that the surjectiveness for the restriction of global sections here $H^0(\mathbb{P}^N,\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^N}(m))\to H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_{X}(m))$ gives an equivalent definition of projective normality.