# Prime ideal of a polynomial ring in 6 variables

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $k$ be a field and $k[x_1,x_2,x_3,y_1,y_2,y_3]$ a polynomial ring in 6 variables over $k$. How to prove that the ideal $(x_1y_2-x_2y_1,x_2y_3-x_3y_2,x_3y_1-x_1y_3)$ is prime in $k[x_1,x_2,x_3,y_1,y_2,y_3]$ ?

Comment: You may get some mileage out of this post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95217/methods-to-check-if-an-ideal-of-a-polynomial-ring-is-prime-or-at-least-radical

Comment: See http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?p=2450856#p2450856 for why your ideal is the kernel of a ring homomorphism between two integral domains (take $n=1$ and $m=2$).

Comment: Use this [result](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/798439/if-a-b-is-an-r-sequence-then-ax-b-is-prime-eisenbud-exercise-10-4).

Comment: Geometrically, Blowing up an irreducible variety yields an irreducible variety.