# Prime ideals in multi-variable polynomial rings over $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals, polynomial-rings

There is a nice classification of prime ideals in the ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, see this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174595/classification-of-prime-ideals-of-mathbbzx).

Is there any generalization of this result, on $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$?

Due to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95217/methods-to-check-if-an-ideal-of-a-polynomial-ring-is-prime-or-at-least-radical), I guess there is not a *'theorem'* for large $n$. However, does anyone know the answer for $n=2$?

> What are the prime ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$?

Comment: See [this MO-question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/127212/prime-ideals-in-polynomial-rings-over-integers). The comments answer the question.